# Register Flash.ocx Exception EOleSysError in Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, ocx

I tried to register Flash.ocx with Regsvr32, but it gave me **Exception EOleSysError**.

For this issue I searched in google and many other websites such as stackoverflow and so on, but I couldn't fix this problem. All found codes that used `DllRegisterServer`, won't work.(like code below)

```
function RegisterOCX(FileName: string): Boolean;
var
 OCXHand: THandle;
 RegFunc: TDllRegisterServer;
begin
 OCXHand := LoadLibrary(PChar(FileName));
 RegFunc := GetProcAddress(OCXHand, 'DllRegisterServer');
 if @RegFunc <> nil then
  Result := RegFunc = S_OK
 else
  Result := False;
 FreeLibrary(OCXHand);
end;
```

I found a solution for this problem and it's, using ShellExecute().

```
ShellExecute(0, 'runas', 'cmd.exe', PChar(' /c Regsvr32.exe /s ' + 'c:\flash.ocx'), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

This solution is working, but I don't want to run it as admin and need to run without admin on any other system with disabled/enabled UAC. Using 'open' Operation is not working.

Comment: Do the program you are executing and the OCX have the same "bitness" -- are you trying to install a 32 bit OCX using a 32 bit program or a 64 bit OCX using a 64 bit program? If not, calling "DllRegisterServer" is going to fail.